# Backbone events don't work in specific view instance

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events

I want to preventDefault event onclick, but i have a problem.
In the other views these events work, but not in this collection view.

```
App.View.Actions = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#actions',
    template: $('#action-tpl').html(),

    //// !!! CALLBACK DOESN'T WORKS
    events: {
        'click .some-link': function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log('!!!!!!');
        }
    },

    initialize: function() {
        /// Event object extends Backbone.Events
        Event.on('actions:dispayActions', this.render, this);
    },

    render: function(data) {
         /// Render logic
    }
});
```

Events for this links:

```
 <a href="http://example.com" class="some-link">Test</a>
```

This view inits with

```
 var actions = new App.View.Actions({ collection: new App.Collection.Actions([{...}, {...}]) });
```

What i do wrong?

Comment: Is `.some-link` inside the view's `el`?

Comment: no, but if I comment "el" declaration and move it to render method, for ex., the problem doesn't fix.

Comment: The things in `events` are bound to the view's `el` using event delegation so events from things outside the `el` will not be seen. Also, a view listening for DOM events on things that aren't inside it is strange and smells like a design problem.

Comment: The easiest way to fix this is to swap the a tag with a button tag and to use CSS to style the button the way you want. Otherwise you have to make sure that .some-link is actually within #actions (i.e. using the debugger)